# Keras - EarlyStopping based on user input

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am wondering if there is an easy way of creating a way of triggering early stopping in Keras based on user input rather than monitorization of any particular metric.

Ie I would like to send a keyboard signal to the process executing the training so that it gets out of the `fit_generator` function and execute the remaining code.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Based on @AnkurGoel 's answer, I wrote this code:

```
# Monitors the SIGINT (ctrl + C) to safely stop training when it is sent
flag = False
class TerminateOnFlag(Callback):
    """Callback that terminates training when the flag is raised.
    """
    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        if flag:    
            self.model.stop_training = True

def handler(signum, frame):
    logging.info('SIGINT signal received. Training will finish after this epoch')
    global flag
    flag = True

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler) # We assign a specific handler for the SIGINT signal
terminateOnFlag = TerminateOnFlag()
callbacks.append(terminateOnFlag)
```

Where `callbacks` is a list of callbacks I fed into `fit_generator`.

During training, when I send the `SIGINT` signal indeed I get the message `SIGINT signal received. Training will finish after this epoch`, but when the epoch ends nothing happens. What is going on?

Comment: How do you send the SIGINT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a thought to approach below:

Use One global variable, initialize 0
Use Signal Handler,

When signal(interrupt) received by the python process, its value is changed from 0 to 1.

Use Custom Callback in Keras, to stop the training when this variable value is changed

```py
    class TerminateOnFlag(Callback):
    """Callback that terminates training when flag=1 is encountered.
    """

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        if flag==1:    
            self.model.stop_training = True
```

Original Callbacks are available at:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L251

You still have to check if it is possible to provide custom callback to fit_generator, instead of standard callbacks.

Here is the code for signal Handler :

For windows:

```py
    import signal, os

    def handler(signum, frame):
        print('Signal handler called with signal', signum)
        raise OSError("Couldn't open device!")

    signal.signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT, handler) # only in python version 3.2
```

For Linux:

```py
    import signal, os

    def handler(signum, frame):
        print('Signal handler called with signal', signum)
        raise OSError("Couldn't open device!")

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
```

Comment: Cool! Custom callbacks are perfectly possible. Can you add the code for the signal handler too? That part is quite new for me

Comment: I hope, the edits i have just made would help you with signal handler part as well. Consider the problem resolved by clicking the Tick (Green) on the left side of this post if i really resolved the issue.

Comment: I must have made some mistake, because I cannot get your solution to work. I have posted my code inspired by your answer in the question, see anything wrong?

Comment: First, lets make sure that callbacks are geeting executed at their expected time(which is on batch end). Try using a simple print statement in the callback to cross check it’s expected behaviour..

Comment: How do you send the SIGINT?

Comment: @jtlz2 CTRL+C on the console for Windows and Linux

Answer (score 2):

Better and safer way is to use mouse as input, for stopping, and other internal interactions.

For example, to stop keras in the end of batch when mouse is moved to the left side (mouse_x<10):

```
def queryMousePosition():
    from ctypes import windll, Structure, c_long, byref
    class POINT(Structure): _fields_ = [("x", c_long), ("y", c_long)]
    pt = POINT()
    windll.user32.GetCursorPos(byref(pt))
    return pt.x, pt.y  # %timeit queryMousePosition()


class TerminateOnFlag(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        mouse_x, mouse_y = queryMousePosition()
        if mouse_x < 10:
            self.model.stop_training = True

callbacks=[keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(), TerminateOnFlag()]

model.fit_generator(..., callbacks=callbacks, ...)
```

Comment: did you post this answer anywhere else? :)

Answer (score 1):

Not using a keyboard signal, but when running Keras in a Jupyter notebook I found it easiest to use a callback that stops training on the presence of a particular file.

```python
TRAINING_POISON_PILL_FILE_NAME = 'stop-training'

class PoisonPillCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback): 
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}): 
        if os.path.exists(TRAINING_POISON_PILL_FILE_NAME):
            self.model.stop_training = True
            os.remove(TRAINING_POISON_PILL_FILE_NAME)
            print(f'poison pill file "{TRAINING_POISON_PILL_FILE_NAME}" detected, stopping training')

model.fit(..., callbacks=[PoisonPillCallback(), ...])
```

Then you can just creat an (empty) file with this name in the current directoy in the Jupyter UI and it will stop training after the current epoch.